# Stored Procedure error handling using java

Tags: java, jdbc, procedure

How do you handle error condition  while writing stored procedure or accessing stored procedure from java?

Comment: Related question: [How to get *everything* back from a stored procedure using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169951/how-to-get-everything-back-from-a-stored-procedure-using-jdbc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stored procedure should return error code if some operation fails but if stored procedure itself fail than catching SQLException is only choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    CallableStatement stmt=con.prepareCall("{call insertR(?,?)}");  
    stmt.setInt(1,1011);  
    stmt.setString(2,"Amit");  
    stmt.execute();  
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStack();
}
```

Comment: @user2156381 on how to handle the SQLexception

Answer (score 0):

```
this piece of code is taken from oracle [docs][1] to answer.

public void
    createProcedureShowSuppliers()
    throws SQLException {
    String createProcedure = null;

    String queryDrop =
        "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SHOW_SUPPLIERS";

    createProcedure =
        "create procedure SHOW_SUPPLIERS() " +
        "begin " +
            "select SUPPLIERS.SUP_NAME, " +
            "COFFEES.COF_NAME " +
            "from SUPPLIERS, COFFEES " +
            "where SUPPLIERS.SUP_ID = " +
            "COFFEES.SUP_ID " +
            "order by SUP_NAME; " +
        "end";
    Statement stmt = null;
    Statement stmtDrop = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("Calling DROP PROCEDURE");
        stmtDrop = con.createStatement();
        stmtDrop.execute(queryDrop);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmtDrop != null)
        {
            stmtDrop.close();
        }
    }

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(createProcedure);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}


  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html
```

Comment: Please include some explanation with the code you're referencing, otherwise your answer isn't really yours

Answer (score 0):

When you call a stored procedure, it will execute in database server so if there any exception occurs that can be handled in EXCEPTION block in the stored procedure. If that stored procedure itself fails, it throws a SQL exception which can be handled by try/catch block and wrap it to your project specific exception.

Example

```
try {
    CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{call geNamebyId(?)}");
    stmt.setInt(1);    
    stmt.execute();    
} catch(SQLException e) {    
    e.printStack();        
}
```