# How to get *everything* back from a stored procedure using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I occasionally encounter two forms of strange behaviour when using JDBC to work with SQL Server stored procedures:

**Issue 1:** I run a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and it returns a result set. However, when I try

```java
try (CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call dbo.TroublesomeSP}")) {
    ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

I get the exception

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

**Issue 2:** I run a stored procedure in SSMS and it raises an error, but when I use JDBC to `.execute` the stored procedure no exception is thrown.

Why do these issues occur and how can I avoid them?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213824/java-sql-statement-hasresultset and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694442/expecting-multiple-resultsets-but-only-get-one and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561550/jdbc-sql-server-raised-error-handling-in-multi-statement-stored-procedures

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we execute a stored procedure in JDBC we get back a series of zero or more "results". We can then process those "results" sequentially by calling `CallableStatement#getMoreResults()`. Each "result" can contain

- zero or more rows of data that we can retrieve with a `ResultSet` object,
- an update count for a DML statement (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) that we can retrieve with `CallableStatement#getUpdateCount()`, or
- an error that throws an SQLServerException.

For "Issue 1" the problem is often that the stored procedure does not begin with `SET NOCOUNT ON;` and executes a DML statement before doing a SELECT to produce a result set. The update count for the DML is returned as the first "result", and the data rows are "stuck behind it" until we call `getMoreResults`.

"Issue 2" is essentially same problem. The stored procedure produces a "result" (usually a SELECT, or possibly an update count) before the error occurs. The error is returned in a subsequent "result" and does not cause an exception until we "retrieve" it using `getMoreResults`.

In many cases the problem can be avoided by simply adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first executable statement in the stored procedure. However, a change to the stored procedure is not always possible and the fact remains that in order to get *everything* back from the stored procedure we need to keep calling `getMoreResults` until, as the Javadoc says:

```
There are no more results when the following is true: 

     // stmt is a Statement object
     ((stmt.getMoreResults() == false) && (stmt.getUpdateCount() == -1))
```

That sounds simple enough but as usual, "the devil is in the details", as illustrated by the following example. For a SQL Server stored procedure ...

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.TroublesomeSP AS
BEGIN
    -- note: no `SET NOCOUNT ON;`
    DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY);

    DROP TABLE NonExistent;
    INSERT INTO @tbl (id) VALUES ('001');
    SELECT id FROM @tbl;
    INSERT INTO @tbl (id) VALUES ('001');  -- duplicate key error
    SELECT 1/0;  -- error _inside_ ResultSet
    INSERT INTO @tbl (id) VALUES ('101');
    INSERT INTO @tbl (id) VALUES ('201'),('202');
    SELECT id FROM @tbl;
END
```

... the following Java code will return everything ...

```java
try (CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call dbo.TroublesomeSP}")) {
    boolean resultSetAvailable = false;
    int numberOfResultsProcessed = 0;
    try {
        resultSetAvailable = cs.execute();
    } catch (SQLServerException sse) {
        System.out.printf("Exception thrown on execute: %s%n%n", sse.getMessage());
        numberOfResultsProcessed++;
    }
    int updateCount = -2;  // initialize to impossible(?) value
    while (true) {
        boolean exceptionOccurred = true; 
        do {
            try {
                if (numberOfResultsProcessed > 0) {
                    resultSetAvailable = cs.getMoreResults();
                }
                exceptionOccurred = false;
                updateCount = cs.getUpdateCount();
            } catch (SQLServerException sse) {
                System.out.printf("Current result is an exception: %s%n%n", sse.getMessage());
            }
            numberOfResultsProcessed++;
        } while (exceptionOccurred);

        if ((!resultSetAvailable) && (updateCount == -1)) {
            break;  // we're done
        }

        if (resultSetAvailable) {
            System.out.println("Current result is a ResultSet:");
            try (ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet()) {
                try {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                    }
                } catch (SQLServerException sse) {
                    System.out.printf("Exception while processing ResultSet: %s%n", sse.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Current result is an update count: %d %s affected%n",
                    updateCount,
                    updateCount == 1 ? "row was" : "rows were");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("[end of results]");
}
```

... producing the following console output:

```
Exception thrown on execute: Cannot drop the table 'NonExistent', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Current result is an update count: 1 row was affected

Current result is a ResultSet:
001

Current result is an exception: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#314D4EA__3213E83F3335971A'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.@tbl'. The duplicate key value is (001).

Current result is a ResultSet:
Exception while processing ResultSet: Divide by zero error encountered.

Current result is an update count: 1 row was affected

Current result is an update count: 2 rows were affected

Current result is a ResultSet:
001
101
201
202

[end of results]
```

Comment: The explanation is great.  The JDBC voodoo stinks.